# Merge data.frames with duplicates

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I have many data.frames, for example:

```
df1 = data.frame(names=c('a','b','c','c','d'),data1=c(1,2,3,4,5))
df2 = data.frame(names=c('a','e','e','c','c','d'),data2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df3 = data.frame(names=c('c','e'),data3=c(1,2))
```

and I need to merge these data.frames, without delete the name duplicates

```
> result
  names data1 data2 data3
1  'a'    1    1      NA
2  'b'    2    NA     NA
3  'c'    3    4      1
4  'c'    4    5      NA
5  'd'    5    6      NA
6  'e'    NA   2      2       
7  'e'    NA   3      NA
```

I cant find function like merge with option to handle with  name duplicates. Thank you for your help.
 To define my problem. The data comes from biological experiment where one sample have a different number of replicates. I need to merge all experiment, and I need to produce this table. I can't generate unique identifier for replicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First define a function, `run.seq`, which provides sequence numbers for duplicates since it appears from the output that what is desired is that the ith duplicate of each name in each component of the merge be associated.  Then create a list of the data frames and add a `run.seq` column to each component.  Finally use `Reduce` to merge them all.

```
run.seq <- function(x) as.numeric(ave(paste(x), x, FUN = seq_along))

L <- list(df1, df2, df3)
L2 <- lapply(L, function(x) cbind(x, run.seq = run.seq(x$names)))

out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), L2)[-2]
```

The last line gives:

```
> out
  names data1 data2 data3
1     a     1     1    NA
2     b     2    NA    NA
3     c     3     4     1
4     c     4     5    NA
5     d     5     6    NA
6     e    NA     2     2
7     e    NA     3    NA
```

EDIT:  Revised `run.seq` so that input need not be sorted.

Comment: This solution work properly only for sorted data, but it is ok for me. Thank you very much, you are the greatest. For this example: df1 = data.frame(names=c('a','b','c','d','c','c'),data1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) df2 = data.frame(names=c('e','c','c','c'),data2=c(1,2,3,4)) it doesn't work without sorting names.

Comment: Have revised `run.seq` so that input need not be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

See other questions:

- [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)
- [recombining-a-list-of-data-frames-into-a-single-data-frame](http://recombining-a-list-of-data-frames-into-a-single-data-frame)
- ...

Examples:

```
library(reshape)
out <- merge_recurse(L)
```

or

```
library(plyr)

out<-join(df1, df2, type="full")
out<-join(out, df3, type="full")
*can be looped
```

or

```
library(plyr)
out<-ldply(L)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is just not enough information in your example data frames to do this. Which `'c'` in dataframe 1 should be paired with which `'c'` in data frame 2? We cannot tell, so R can't either. I suspect you will have to add another variable to each of your dataframes that uniquely identifies these duplicate cases.

Comment: It is not important which 'c' in data frame 1 should be paired with 'c' from data frame 2 (I think, that the first free will be the best, and when all will be paired new row should be created). I know that with duplicate identifiers it is not so easy.